# Reading a file and displaying wanted results

Tags: java

I have a program that reads files like the one below.

```
12  9-62-1                      

Sample Name:        9-62-1          Injection Volume:       25.0  
Vial Number:        37          Channel:        ECD_1
Sample Type:        unknown         Wavelength:     n.a.
Control Program:        Anions Run          Bandwidth:      n.a.
Quantif. Method:        Anions Method           Dilution Factor:        1.0000  
Recording Time:     10/2/2013 19:55         Sample Weight:      1.0000  
Run Time (min):     14.00           Sample Amount:      1.0000  






No.     Ret.Time    Peak Name   Height  Area    Rel.Area    Amount  Type 
    min     µS  µS*min  %   mG/L    
1   2.99        Fluoride    7.341   1.989   0.87        10.458  BMB
2   3.88        Chloride    425.633     108.551     47.72       671.120     BMb
3   4.54        Nitrite 397.537     115.237     50.66       403.430     bMB
4   5.39        n.a.    0.470   0.140   0.06        n.a.    BMB
5   11.22       Sulfate 4.232   1.564   0.69        13.064  BMB
Total:          835.213     227.482     100.00      1098.073
```

From these files, the program should output a few things not everything. 
The final results that I need should look like this:

```
0012.TXT
Sample#,Date,Time,Peak Name, Amount
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Fluoride,10.458
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Chloride,671.120
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Nitrite,403.430 
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Sulfate,13.064
```

But, right now they look like this:

```
0012.TXT
Sample#,Date,Time,Peak Name, Amount
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Fluoride,10.458 ,
Chloride,671.120 ,
Nitrite,403.430 ,
n.a.,n.a.,
Sulfate,13.064 ,
,1098.073 ,
```

Here is my code and what I have done.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
                    System.out.println("Sample#,Date,Time,Peak Name,Amount");

                    int linesToSkip = 28;

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));

                        String line;
                        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if (linesToSkip-- > 0) {
                            continue;
                            }
                            if (line.contains("n.a.")) {
                            continue;
                            }
                            if (line.contains("Total")) { 
                                continue;
                            }

                            String[] values = line.split("\t");

                            int index = 0;
                            for (String value : values) {
                                /*System.out.println("values[" + index + "] = " + value);*/
                                index++;



                                }

                                while (input.hasNext()) {

                                        String word = input.next();
                                        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("Name:");
                                        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("Time:");
                                        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(word);
                                        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(word);
                                        Matcher matcher3 = pattern2.matcher(word);

                                        if(matcher1.matches()){
                                            System.out.print(input.next() + ",");
                                        }
                                        if(matcher2.matches()){
                                            System.out.print(input.next() + ",");
                                        }
                                        if(matcher3.matches()){
                                            System.out.print(input.next() + ",");
                                        } 
                                        System.out.print("");
                                }

                                System.out.print(values[2]+",");
                                System.out.println(values[6]+"\b,"); 


                        }
                   br.close();
```

How can I make the output look like these with the sample#, Date and Time then followed by the peak name and amount and print them that way on each line?

```
Sample#,Date,Time,Peak Name, Amount
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Fluoride,10.458
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Chloride,671.120
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Nitrite,403.430 
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Sulfate,13.064
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if (line.contains("n.a.")) {
       continue;
     }

//Your code
```

You can do the same in your inner `while` loop for specific table item for `peak name value` and the `amount value`. In that case you can use  [String#equales()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

---

**Edit for Comments:**

You are over complicating your things while printing and reading your file content. Dont use `Scanner` as well as `BufferedReader`. One will do the work for you.

You have very specific format for your file. You really dont need to use `regex` for this purpose, which you are using in your inner `while` loop.

For `sample name` to match use `String#equales()` method and do you operations accordingly.

1. Get the values you needed from upper section of your file like `Sample Name` and `Recording Time`, keep them handy, so that you could use them later.
2. From you lower section get  `Peak Name` and `amount` from each row.
3. While printing construct your `String` by making use of these collected values.

---

**Another Edit for Comments:**

the following code is not tested, so there could be some issues, but you can figure them out.
If you look at [String Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) then you will find many useful methods.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));

String recTime, peakName, amount, sample ;
int linesToSkip = 28;
String line = br.readLine();

if(line != null){
    String[] values = line.split("\t");
    sample = values[1];
}

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    values = line.split("\t");

    if (line.startsWith("Sample Name")) { 
       // Check here value[1] is equal to sample. If this is needed.
       // You got your sample name here 
    } else if (line.startsWith("Recording Time")) { 
       recTime = values[1];
       // You got your Recording Time here 
    } else if(values.length > 4 ){
       // get Peak Name and recording time
       peakName = values[2];
       amount = values[6];
    } else if (line.contains("n.a.") || line.contains("Total") || linesToSkip-- > 0) {
       /* may not needed linesToSkip-- > 0 in above condition */ 
       continue;
    } 

    System.out.println(sample +" ," + recTime + " ," + peakName + " ," + amount);
}
```

I hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks. I used it to skip the last line as well since I don`t need it.

Comment: How can I make it print like this?

Comment: Sample#,Date,Time,Peak Name, Amount
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Fluoride,10.458
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Chloride,671.120
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Nitrite,403.430 
9-62-1,10/2/2013,19:55,Sulfate,13.064 @Smit

Comment: I really dont understand. Can you edit this in your post? Currently its unreadble in your comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. It`s fixed on my post now. @Smit

Comment: I`m trying to follow your advice, but I don`t know how to iterate the loop so that it prints the sample#, date and time for every peak name and amount value. @Smit

Comment: What are you currently doing to get those values, Can you edit your updated code? Its pretty simple as you are doing it right now. Before printing `values[2]` and `values[6]`, print your `Sample name` and `Time` which you read previously.

Comment: I now posted my edited code. I understand what you mean, but I start reading from the 28th line and iterate from there if I don`t start from the 28th line other values will be printed that I don`t need. @Smit

Comment: I have updated the answer. It may not be very correct for your requirements, but will give you idea to accomplish your goal.